# Catch React Warnings During Testing

Tags: reactjs, key, cypress

Let's consider this [example from the React docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists#rendering-data-from-arrays):

```js
const people = [
  'Creola Katherine Johnson: mathematician',
  'Mario José Molina-Pasquel Henríquez: chemist',
  'Mohammad Abdus Salam: physicist',
  'Percy Lavon Julian: chemist',
  'Subrahmanyan Chandrasekhar: astrophysicist'
];

export default function List() {
  const listItems = people.map(person =>
    <li>{person}</li>
  );
  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}
```

When rendering this component, React will write the following to the console:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I want to ensure that my components do not exhibit this problem. Is there a way to check with [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) (or another tool) that React has not raised this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Replace built-in window methods like prompt](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/stub#Replace-built-in-window-methods-like-prompt), you can spy or stub the warn method on the app's window.

In this example, I also used an alias to track the calls, then check the call count at the end of the test.

```js
cy.visit('/', {
  onBeforeLoad(win) {
    cy.spy(win, 'warn').as('warnings')
  },
})

// run the test

cy.get('@warnings').should('not.be.called')
```

Comment: Thanks. While that answers the question directly, I think it would be worthwhile to recommend using eslint for this task by pointing to https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-key.md. The eslint rule seems more precise and has more capabilities.